# Celery Task State Not getting Store into Django-Celery Database

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery

I'm running Celery(3.1.26) with Django(2.0.5) and want to see the task states in the database table. Unfortunately no entries are written into the table djcelery_taskstate and I can't figure out why.

My settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',
    'djkombu',
    'cdm',
]

BROKER_URL="django://"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('cdm.tasks.autodiscover')

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

My Task:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import time
from celery import task

@task
def auto():
    for i in range(10):
        print('celery task=>',i)
        time.sleep(2)
```

I am running `python manage.py celerycam` also, still I am not getting anything in the table, please help in that.

Comment: how do you start your celery worker? what command is the celerycam?

Comment: @MazelTov `python manage.py celeryd --loglevel=info` for starting celery worker and `python manage.py celerycam` for celerycam

Comment: are your tasks running OK (worker process them)? in the github they say you have to invoke it with `python manage.py celery worker`

Comment: did u start a Celery instance? `celery -A my_project worker -l info`?